# 4D matrix calculation, Matlab coding problem

Tags: variables, matlab, loops

hey guys, I got some difficulty here. It is purely coding algorithm problem. Okay, the program is shown below:

```
for f=1:(nFrames-1)
    h=histogram(imgYuv(:,:,1,f));
    j=histogram(imgYuv(:,:,1,f+1));
    X=abs(h-j)/256; %normalize the difference
    S=sum(X);
end
```

Basically, I want to calculate the difference between two adjacent elements and store the sum result in an 1-D array `S`. But the result I got from the above program is one single number. I expected it to be an 1-D array because `f` is varying from `1` to `nFrames-1`. Can anybody help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: the last line should be: `S(f)=sum(X);` assuming the vector `S` is already preallocated

Comment: @Amro, why don't you submit it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of the for-loop should be:

```
for f=1:(nFrames-1)
    %# ...
    S(f) = sum(X);
end
```

assuming the vector `S` is already preallocated: `S = zeros(nFrames-1,1);`